# Replacing opening a cv2 window with RTSP in python

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtsp

I recently moved from an nvidia devkit to a "headless board". I have this simple opencv face detector code working on the devkit which very nicely opens up a display on my connected monitor and detects my face:

```python
import cv2

def gstreamer_pipeline(
    capture_width=1920,
    capture_height=1080,
    display_width=960,
    display_height=540,
    framerate=30,
    flip_method=0,
):
    return (
        "nvarguscamerasrc ! "
        "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), "
        "width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, framerate=(fraction)%d/1 ! "
        "nvvidconv flip-method=%d ! "
        "video/x-raw, width=(int)%d, height=(int)%d, format=(string)BGRx ! "
        "videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink drop=True"
        % (
            capture_width,
            capture_height,
            framerate,
            flip_method,
            display_width,
            display_height,
        )
    )


def face_detect():
    window_title = "Face Detect"
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
        "/usr/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
    )
    eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
        "/usr/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml"
    )
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_pipeline(), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
    if video_capture.isOpened():
        try:
            cv2.namedWindow(window_title, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
            while True:
                ret, frame = video_capture.read()
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                    roi_gray = gray[y : y + h, x : x + w]
                    roi_color = frame[y : y + h, x : x + w]
                    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
                    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
                        cv2.rectangle(
                            roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2
                        )
                # Check to see if the user closed the window
                # Under GTK+ (Jetson Default), WND_PROP_VISIBLE does not work correctly. Under Qt it does
                # GTK - Substitute WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE to detect if window has been closed by user
                if cv2.getWindowProperty(window_title, cv2.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) >= 0:
                    cv2.imshow(window_title, frame)
                else:
                    break
                keyCode = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
                # Stop the program on the ESC key or 'q'
                if keyCode == 27 or keyCode == ord('q'):
                    break
        finally:
            video_capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print("Unable to open camera")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    face_detect()
```

Now however, since Im headless, I want to stream the opencv video output via RTSP to my windows host machine running VLC.

I have the following RTSP Example working:

```python
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst','1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo','1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer','1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo, GstRtspServer

Gst.init(None)

mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()
server = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
mounts = server.get_mount_points()

face_stream = GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory()

face_stream.set_launch('( nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=1 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=1 idrinterval=15 insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )')

mounts.add_factory("/test", face_stream)
server.attach(None)



print( "stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test")

mainloop.run()
```

I was kindly wondering how I could edit my opencv script to include the output to RTSP as opposed to opening up that cv2 window. Thanks so much!

I tried replacing the gstreamer_pipeline definition with the gi overhead and simply modified the line

`video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(gstreamer_pipeline(), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`

to

`video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(face_stream, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`

but get the following error:

```
  File "face_detect.py", line 68, in face_detect
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(face_stream, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'VideoCapture'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
>  - Required argument 'params' (pos 3) not found
>  - Argument 'index' is required to be an integer
>  - Required argument 'params' (pos 3) not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass any objects from the `gi` package into a `VideoCapture`.

The only accepted argument types are

- integers: indices for cameras
- strings: for files/URLs, gst pipeline descriptions

Since you just want to watch your script run, you don't need OpenCV to display the stream. Use VLC or whatever.

Or don't bother streaming this yourself. Just run a VNC server instead. There are recipes for Raspberry Pi, which are probably easily adaptable to your situation.